# How to handle multiple change events in one handler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onchange

I'm listening for the `onChangeText` of three inputs in a view. But instead of using three separate `onChangeText` handlers. I would like to pass in the input state name of the input to the handler and have it set state from that.

I tried this example but e.target.value returns `undefined`. Passing in the `name` as the second parameter and `e` as the pointer to the element:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Alert, Image, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    setValue: 0,
    travelValue: 0,
    runValue: 0

  };


  _handleTextChange (e, name) {
      var change = {};
      change[name] = e.target.value;
      this.setState(change);
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>


        <TextInput
          value={this.state.setValue}
          keyboardType = 'numeric'
          onChangeText={this._handleTextChange.bind(this, 'setValue')}
          style={{ width: 200, height: 44, padding: 8 }}
        />
         <TextInput
          value={this.state.travelValue}
          keyboardType = 'numeric'
          onChangeText={this._handleTextChange.bind(this, 'travelValue')}
          style={{ width: 200, height: 44, padding: 8 }}
        />
         <TextInput
          value={this.state.runValue}
          keyboardType = 'numeric'
          onChangeText={this._handleTextChange.bind(this, 'runValue')}
          style={{ width: 200, height: 44, padding: 8 }}
        />

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    paddingBottom: '20%',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
});
```

**Question:**

How can you handle multiple change events in one handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you used in wrong order, use it like this:

```
_handleTextChange (name, e) {  //first name then event
    var change = {};
    change[name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState(change);
}
```

You can write it like this also, define a `name` property to Input element then access that `name` by `e.target.name`, Like this:

```
<TextInput
    value={this.state.setValue}
    name='setValue'
    onChangeText={this._handleTextChange}
    ....
```

`Bind` the `_handleTextChange function` in the `constructor`:

```
this._handleTextChange = this._handleTextChange.bind(this);
```

Use the `_handleTextChange` like this:

```
_handleTextChange(e){
      var change = {};
      change[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
      this.setState(change);
}
```